# How can I download a file from its download link provided on a webpage using java?

Tags: java, url, hyperlink

How can I download a file from its download link provided on a webpage using java? For example, I want to download this file: http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss  from http://edition.cnn.com/services/rss/  using Java. What should be my initial steps to accomplish it?

Comment: Look at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/examples.html

Comment: If I didn't know how I would use Google and search for `java download file from server`. Lots of info there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335610/java-code-to-download-a-file-from-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically RSS is a XML file. You can download it as a regular file if you want.. See if following link helps

[How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, [httpunit?](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/) Its sophisticated but I dont know any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Java library like [JSoup.](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to know if there is any other way other than using JSoup library which would be included in packages provided by JDK?